# UITableView reload data not triggering all cellForRowAtIndexPath instruction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have this code in `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```objectivec
    [self.menuTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCellNotif" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"notifCell"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"notifCell"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
    if (loaded == 2) {
        DLOG(@"loaded 2");            
        
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:cell.bounds.size.height*30/100];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"some text";
        
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:cell.bounds.size.height*20/100];
        
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
        
        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(mydate / 1000)];
        
        NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = formattedDateString;
                    
    } else if (loaded == 4) {
        DLOG(@"loaded 4");
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:cell.bounds.size.height*30/100];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Loaded 4";
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:cell.bounds.size.height*20/100];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Loaded 4";
    } else {
        DLOG(@"loaded 0");
        
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:cell.bounds.size.height*30/100];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"NOthing";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
    }
```

And I am fetching data in another method which contains this:

```objectivec
    /* request is here */
    if (error != nil) {
         DLOG(@"error :%@",error);

         loaded = 4;

         [self.tableView reloadData];

     } else {

         DLOG(@"Success! Response from the back");
         /* ... fetching data */
     }

     if ([self.listResult count] == 0) {
          loaded = 0;
     } else {
          loaded = 2;
     }
    DLOG(@"loaded : %i", loaded);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

My log look like this:

```
2015-06-23 10:07:47.279 myproject[199:11514] __54-[MyTableViewController fetchData]_block_invoke: Success! Response from the back
2015-06-23 10:07:47.280 myproject[199:11514] __54-[MyTableViewController fetchData]_block_invoke: loaded : 2
2015-06-23 10:07:47.282 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: 
2015-06-23 10:07:47.283 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: 
2015-06-23 10:07:47.288 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: 
2015-06-23 10:07:47.289 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: loaded 2
2015-06-23 10:07:47.301 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: 
2015-06-23 10:07:47.305 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: loaded 2
2015-06-23 10:07:47.351 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: 
2015-06-23 10:07:47.355 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: loaded 2
2015-06-23 10:07:47.395 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: 
2015-06-23 10:07:47.399 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: loaded 2
2015-06-23 10:07:47.439 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: 
2015-06-23 10:07:47.443 myproject[199:11514] -[MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: loaded 2
```

I have my 5 cell with their text, my only problem is that only the first has the good font size, other will be default font size. However if I go to another view and come back (which triggers the exact same actions), everything is fine. How do I get the good font on the first call?

Comment: How are you reloading ??

Comment: I use [tableView reloadData] after fetching data. For instance, if I have 6 new data, it will go through the function 6 times printing "loaded 2" in the logs the date will be printed and the textLabel will be updated but only the 1st cell will have the good font. and if I change view and come back (triggering fetch again) everything will be ok (note that I do the same thing twice but the second time it works)

Comment: based from your log only `if (loaded == 2)` is called, is that correct?

Comment: It is, but as I said in my answer, the real problem is that heightForRowAtIndexPath is called after cellForRowAtIndexPath even if it is supposed to be the other way around, I still looking for the reason.

Answer (score 0):

First of when using:

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"notifCell"];
```

require you to implement cell creation if that returns nil.

Use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` which always returns a cell.

And solution for you will be to call

```
[tableView reloadData]
```

which will reload all visible cells, but you need to make sure you call it after you set `loaded` to desired value, not before that.

Also make sure that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` is returning proper amount of rows for your case.

Comment: I am using [self.menuTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCellNotif" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"notifCell"]; (sorry I didn't say that)
and I am triggering [tableView reloadData] after loading data. my number of rows is good, I have the good number of cell with good texts, only the font isn't good. I will update my first post to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found, in fact the cell.bounds.size.height was wrong all along because

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

was called AFTER

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

That's why the font size was wrong with the % of cell height. Now I just have to find a way to call heightForRow before the other method.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to user answer is to store the heights in a `NSMutableArray` then use it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, meaning calculate the heights first before reloading the table..

then under your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will look something like:

eq: `NSMutableArray *heights;` holds the calculated heights

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: ([heights[indexPath.row] floatValue]) * (30/100) ];
```